# Spring4 issue- Setter methods with Spring @Qualifier annotation not getting invoked

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-4

I have migrated my project from spring-3.1.2 and java-6 to Spring-4.1.6 and java-8. Setter methods with Spring @Qualifier annotation are not invoked after this migration resulting in null values for the given variables.

**Please note that there is no spring exception thrown. Just that Spring-4 does not invokes the setter methods with @Qualifier annotation.**

The beans are in different package from this class package. However, the corresponding package is imported in my class.

Kindly advice if additional Spring-4(version- 4.1.6) configuration is needed?

Below is sample code-snippet:

My class with 2 private attributes:

```
private ExtractionContextBasedSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProvider<AssetId> syntheticAwareProvider;
private ExtractionContextBasedSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProvider<AssetId> sfmSyntheticAwareProvider;
```

Corresponding setters methods are:

```
public void setSyntheticAwareProvider(
        @Qualifier("extractionContextBasedSyntheticAssetIdentitiesProvider") ExtractionContextBasedSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProvider<AssetId> syntheticAwareProvider) {
    this.syntheticAwareProvider = syntheticAwareProvider;
}

public void setSfmSyntheticAwareProvider(
        @Qualifier("extractionContextBasedSfmSyntheticAssetIdentitiesProvider") ExtractionContextBasedSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProvider<AssetId> sfmSyntheticAwareProvider) {
    this.sfmSyntheticAwareProvider = sfmSyntheticAwareProvider;
}
```

Corresponding beans.xml is:

```
<bean id="extractionContextBasedSfmSyntheticAssetIdentitiesProvider"
    class="com.package.ExtractionContextBasedSfmSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProviderImpl">
    <property name="sfmSyntheticAwareAssetPidDAO" ref="sfmSyntheticAwareAssetPidDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="extractionContextBasedSyntheticAssetIdentitiesProvider"
    class="com.package.ExtractionContextBasedSyntheticAwareAssetIdentitiesProviderImpl">
    <property name="syntheticAwareAssetPidDAO" ref="syntheticAwareAssetPidDAO" />
</bean>
```

Comment: The `@Qualifer` does nothing here, as you aren't using autowiring but explicit wiring using xml. If you are using autowiring you would also have to annotate the method with `@Autowired` and you should remove the xml configuration as that doesn't make any sense in having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting below spring jira- SPR-9965, until Spring-4, there's no general support for injecting generic types in a type safe way.

The issue resulted because generic types were not properly handled in our application legacy code. With spring-4 generics support, it became obvious. I have corrected our application code.

Futher, documentation and reference can be found at:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9965

https://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics